# php prompt user to download pdf

Tags: php, angularjs, pdf

I'm receiving a binary pdf file from a angular $http.get request. I'm trying to open a dialog to prompt the user to download the file using readfile() but no dialog is displayed. Also, is there a way to just use the binary data, without writing it to the file system to use with readfile(), in order to prompt the user to download the file?

```
return $http({
            method: 'get',
            url: env.baseUri + '/1.0/releases/report/file?regions=' + regionIds
        })
        .then(
            function (response) {
                getPdfFactory.getPdf(response.data)
                .then(function(pdf){
                   // replace with php
                    //window.open("data:application/pdf;base64, " + pdf.data);
                    ...


<?php 
    if(isset($_POST)) {
        $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
        $binary = json_decode($postdata);
  //       $base64pdf = base64_encode($binary);  
        file_put_contents("../../../src/uploads/report.pdf", $binary);
  //           echo $base64pdf;

        $file = "../../../src/uploads/report.pdf";
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile($file);
        exit;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a form for the post data and set the action to the php script, which fixed the issue of not downloading the file to the user's machine. The issue was with submitting data to the php script from an ajax post request, where the response will be returned to the ajax process before the php download process can happen.